# Weird variable expansion

Tags: fish

Please consider the following code

```
function test1
echo count:(count $argv) argv: $argv
end

function test2
echo count:(count $argv) argv:$argv
end

test1 ci -m "test1 str2"
test2 ci -m "test2 str2"
```

why am I getting this output?!

```
~  source test.fish                                   Sat Nov  2 12:18:26 EDT 2013
count:3 argv: ci -m test1 str2
count:3 argv:ci argv:-m argv:test2 str2
```

note the argv: repetition on the second call.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This relates to the way variables are expanded. If a variable contains more than one element (is a list), and an argument contains a variable, then the argument is expanded *separately* for each element in the list.

For example:

```
> set vals 1 2 3
> echo item_$vals
item_1 item_2 item_3
```

So in the sample code:

```
test1 ci -m "test1 str2"
```

This invokes the test1 function with $argv set to a list of three elements: `ci`, `-m`, and `test2 str2`.

```
echo argv: $argv
```

Spaces separate arguments, so the text `argv: $argv` contains two separate (unexpanded) arguments. They get expanded separately.

Now for the second case:

```
echo argv:$argv
```

The text `argv:$argv` contains no spaces, so it is just one (unexpanded) argument. Therefore fish separately expands the text for every element in the list, yielding three arguments:

```
argv:$argv
→ argv:{ci, -m, test2 str}
→ argv:ci argv:-m argv:test2 str
```

Those arguments are then passed to echo.

If you don't want this expansion behavior, you can use double quotes, which always results in a single argument. In double quotes, list variables are joined using a space:

```
> set vals 1 2 3
> echo "item_$vals"
item_1 2 3
```

The quoted string expanded to a single argument (that contained spaces).

For completeness, single quotes defeat variable expansion entirely:

```
> set vals 1 2 3
> echo 'item_$vals'
item_$vals
```

The unquoted list expansion behavior is useful for constructing patterns. To generate a list of file1.txt through file5.txt:

```
> echo file(seq 5).txt
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt file5.txt
```

Hope that clears things up.